# Rhino Mocks - Difference between GenerateStub<T> & GenerateMock<T>

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Can any of the Rhino experts explain me by giving a suitable example of the difference between the above methods on the `MockRepository` class (Rhino Mocks framework).

Where should one use Stub over Mock method or otherwise?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

you should use a mock when you are going to verify that something happened on the object, like a method was called.  You should use a stub when you just want the object to be involved in the test to return a value but it is not the thing you are testing.  A stub which does not have a expectation fulfilled can never fail a test.

I think the general rule should be that you should only ever have a single mock object in a test, but may have several stubs which provide information to the mock object.  I believe that more than 1 mock in a test is a code smell.

Although not a Rhino example [Martin Fowler has a description of the difference](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs)

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477924/rhino-mocks-stub-expect-vs-assertwascalled) might be useful as might [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288168/when-to-use-stubs-and-mocks)