# Rhino Mocks: Stub & Mocks. What is the difference

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, stub

I'm using Rhino Mocks in my unit test.

I would like to know the difference between STUBS and MOCKS (`mocks.Stub<T>()` and  `mocks.StrictMock<T>()`).

Answer (score 6):

I think it had been asked before.

It is generally the same with the following differences:

- **Strict Mocks** throw exceptions on each call which had not been expected
- **Dynamic Mocks** accept unexpected calls und just return default values (eg. null)
- **Stubs** are like dynamic mocks but have "property behaviour" turned on by default. This allows writing and reading properties like fields, but doesn't allow `Stub`, `Expect` nor `AssertWasCalled` on properties. This behaviour can also be configured on a normal Mock too. But for stubs it is the default.

Since Rhino changed to [AAA syntax](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx), it is discouraged to use Strict Mocks, since they make test code very hard to maintain.

---

Similar questions:

- [What are the differences between mocks and stubs on Rhino Mocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463707/what-are-the-differences-between-mocks-and-stubs-on-rhino-mocks)
- [Rhino Mocks - Difference between GenerateStub<T> & GenerateMock<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536551/rhino-mocks-difference-between-generatestubt-generatemockt)

I can't find the information about the Rhino implementation, so I don't mark this question as duplicate.