# GenerateMock<T> and GenerateStub<T> Which one to use in specific scenario

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Following is a simple TestMethod which which passes successfully using `ITestInterface`

```
ITestInterface mockProxy = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITestInterface>();
```

OR

```
ITestInterface mockProxy = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ITestInterface>();
```

Can someone help me which one to use in this specific scenario.

Following is TestMethod for testing a business layer method and x.Method is a Data Access Layer method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    ITestInterface mockProxy = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITestInterface>();

    ITestInterface mockProxy = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ITestInterface>();

    mockProxy.Stub(x => x.Method(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Return(10);

    var result = mockProxy.BusinessLayerMethod(10);

    Assert.AreEqual(10, result);
}
```

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/q/2536551/373706

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario does not make sense at all. Surely the test method passed successfully, `RhinoMocks` works as expected ;) You just hard coded return value for a method to be `10` and then simply verifying whether a method call on either Mock/Stub returns this value, this is fine test case to test `RhinoMocks` itself but not any custom behaviour (in this case your DAL behaviour)