# Error in Mocking in c# Setup for return Value of a function

Tags: c#, tdd, rhino-mocks

```
interface ITaxi
{
    int Fare { get; set; }
    int getTotalFare();        
}


class Taxi : Car, ITaxi
{

    public Taxi(Engine e) : base (e){ }        

    public int Fare { get; set; }
    public int getTotalFare()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


[TestFixture]
class TestTaxi
{
    [Test]
    public void TestTaxiFare()
    {
        MockRepository mockRepo = new MockRepository();
        ITaxi taxi = mockRepo.Stub<ITaxi>();
        using (mockRepo.Record())
        {
            SetupResult.For(taxi.getTotalFare()).Return(400);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(400, taxi.getTotalFare());
    }
}
```

i'm new to Test Driven Development. i tried to mock a class and setuo a value for the method.
but i

```
message castle.dynamicProxy.generators.generatorexception Type is not public, so a proxy cannot be generated. type: UnitTest.ITaxi
```

1. did i miss anything in code?
2. what's difference between stub and mock? [i read links didn't understand]?

Comment: A stub is a class that simply conforms to it's contract - ie, it will return the correct type values but that's it. A mock is a class that is "mocked" to perform some function and return specific values.

Comment: [Know Your Test Doubles](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/testing-on-toilet-know-your-test-doubles.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the others you need to declare the interface as Public.

The difference between a mock and a stub is quite subtle (from my understanding of Roy Osherove's [Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) book).

- A stub is something that assists with the test but can never fail the test as the actual test is asserted against the Class Under Test.
- A mock can fail a test as the assertion is performed against that object.

To maybe further explain, a stub is a canned response (a fake object) which assists with performing the assertion later (i.e. it can be a parameter to a method you are testing). You would never assert that a stub passes or fails a test as it's an object you have configured to assist in testing something else

A mock on the otherhand has expectations set, for example, if I configure this object with set of parameters what do I expect to happen? Will it change it's internal state (as I expect) or does it throw an exception (that I expect). This is the assertion you are looking to test.

In more complicated tests you could have many stubs but you should aim to only have one mock.

Comment: still i didn't get the difference.

Comment: @Dineshkumar I've added a bit more info, does that help?

Comment: when i say class which one should i use? generateMock<T> or generateStub<T> ?

Comment: @Dineshkumar, depends on what you are testing. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536551/rhino-mocks-difference-between-generatestubt-generatemockt

Answer (score 2):

You must declare the interface `public` for Rhino Mocks to be able to create a mock:

```
public interface ITaxi
{
    int Fare { get; set; }
    int getTotalFare();        
}
```

See also [Access Modifiers in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Comment: why it needs to be public?

Answer (score 0):

change class to public

```
public class Taxi : Car, ITaxi

interface ITaxi
```

by default it isnot public